# Function to count same numbers in array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, binary-search

I have this function that is supposed to count how many duplicates of same number occur in certain array. Important this must be of complexity O(logn).
I wrote this one below, but it doesn't count the duplicates properly.
Also one more thing, the numbers are sorted from lowest to highest.

```
int CountElementsinFile(int *Arr, int num, int numOfD)
{
    int avg{}; 
    int inB = 0; 
    int inE = numOfD - 1; 
    int el{};
    while (inB <= inE)
    {
        avg = (inB + inE) / 2;

        if (Arr[avg] == num)
            el++;
            if (Arr[avg] > num)
                inE = avg - 1;
            else
                inB = avg + 1;
    }

    return el;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the input values and also show the results and desired results?

Comment: Is the array sorted?  I'm not sure how you could find all duplicates in less then O(N)

Comment: are you sure about the time complexity ?

Comment: to find duplicates you need to touch every element at least once, O(logn) is not possible

Comment: Yes the array is sorted as I wrote

Comment: sorted does not really help that much, eg when you know that `arr[3] == 3` and `arr[5] == 5` you still have to inspect `arr[4]` to know what value it has

Comment: You just need to count how many 2's or 3's are there when you know that the 1st 2 is on index X and the last 2 is on index Y you know that there are Y-X 2's

Comment: [std::equal_range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) might help.

Comment: You need to determine the upper and lower boundaries of `num` subsequence using the dichotomy method. The difference of this values is subsequence length. Your implementation of the dichotomy method is incorrect.

Comment: Worst case will still be O(n) as you are potentially counting the largest number in the list.

Comment: Could you show me an example?

Comment: @user463035818 Yeah but you don't have to look at arr[0] or arr[1] or arr[2] or arr[6] or arr[7] or arr[8] or arr[9] or arr[10] or arr[11] or arr[12] or arr[13] or arr[14] so yes it helps a lot

Answer (score 2):

With std, you might do:

```
int CountElementsinFile(const int *a, int size, int value)
{
    const auto range = std::equal_range(a, a + size, value);
    return range.second - range.first;
}
```

Comment: While true and a good solution for the real world, it seems clear that the OP is supposed to design the _algorithm_ not just use an existing implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to determine the upper and lower boundaries of `num` subsequence using the [Bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method). You need to rearrange the lower or upper (depending on the comparison) search region boundary in the while loop until `inB < inE` reducing the region in half. The complexity will be `O(ln(n))`. You were close, but you will not be able to find both boundaries in one `while` loop. I just corrected your code.

```
int CountElementsinFile(int *Arr, int num, int numOfD)
{
   // There is no num in the array
   if (Arr[0] > num || Arr[numOfD - 1] < num)
      return 0;

   int avg{};
   int lb, ub;

   // Find lower boundary
   int inB = 0;
   int inE = numOfD - 1;
   while (inB < inE)
   {
      // divide search region
      avg = (inB + inE) / 2;
      if (Arr[avg] >= num)
         inE = avg;
      else
         inB = avg+1;
   }

   lb = inE;

   // Find upper boundary   
   // inB already found
   inE = numOfD - 1;
   while (inB < inE)
   {
      avg = (inB + inE + 1) / 2;
      if (Arr[avg] > num)
         inE = avg-1;
      else
         inB = avg;
   }

   ub = inB;

   return ub - lb + 1;
}

int main()
{
   int arr[] = { 5, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 11 };
   std::cout << CountElementsinFile(arr, 9, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int)) << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: split the method makes sense, and would make code clearer.

Answer (score 0):

From the function signature you gave, I am guessing you were given a number N and a sorted array of numbers and need to count how many times N appears in the array.

Since the array is sorted, you need to find the index (using binary search) of the first number that is smaller than N (this is `O(log n)`), the index of the first number larger than N (this is also `O(log n)`), and simply substract one index from the other.
Of course you need to take into account edge cases where there are no numbers smaller than N *or* larger than N, but that is for you to figure out.

Comment: standard with algorithm comes with `std::lower_bound`/`std::upper_bound` for that.and `std::equal_range` when both are required.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int CountElementsinFile(int arr[], int size, int numToSearch)
{
    return count(arr, arr + size, numToSearch); 
}
```

Comment: You are in linear complexity. whereas `arr` is sorted, we might have better complexity.